# Transparent Proxy

Tags: centos, iptables, routing, proxy

I am setting up attempting to set up a transparent proxy on CentOS using Squid. So far I have managed to filter the content and get it working perfectly. The only issue I am having is getting a form of portforwarding to work. The way I'd like it to work is let my router handle portforwarding and the proxy just let all data go from the internet to the lan(dependent on the source IP).

My set up is like so:

> eth0 - Internet (My main router)
>   eth1 -  LAN (10.0.0.0/24)
>   eth1:0 - LAN (81.150.192.224/28)

How would I make it so that any requests to the `81.150.192.224/28` network are sent to the correct machine on the interface: `eth1:0` and any requests to the `10.0.0.0/24` network are sent to the correct machine on the interface: `eth1` ?

I am using `iptables` and CentOS 6.5.